# Excel Returns Null After Line 144 using C# Microsoft Interop Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

In C#, I've opened an Excel spreadsheet and I am iterating through it.  Whenever I get to line 144, the spreadsheet value returns null for every single line following it.  Looking at the spreadsheet, it is clearly not null for lines 144 - 250.  I tried saving it in different versions but that didn't work.  I've tried copying and pasting into a brand new worksheet.  Nothing has worked. Here is my code:

```
        // initiate Excel
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(lblFileName.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Get the used Range
        Excel.Range usedRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        //Iterate the rows in the used range
        string customerNumber;
        string amount;
        int i = 0;
        decimal dAmount = 0;

        bool runProcess = true;
        bool hasHeader = false;
        string cellValue;
        foreach (Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows)
        {
            i++; 
            // Column 1 is customer number
            // THE FOLLOWING LINE RETURNS NULL STARTING AT ROW 144
            cellValue = row.Cells[i, 1].Value2 == null ? "" : row.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
            if (!(cellValue.Length >= 5 && cellValue.Length <= 20))
            {
                    MessageBox.Show(cellValue + " Must be between 5 and 20 Characters - File Will Not Be Processed Row#" + i.ToString());
                    runProcess = false;
            }

        }
        // run process
        // release EXCEL
```

I did try  row.Cells[i, 1].Value2,  row.Cells[i, 1].Value and  row.Cells[i, 1].Text and got the same results for all.  I am including "using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;"

Sample Data from Excel

```
 4492605768531895  15.95
 4492605768536544  19.95
 4492605768565459  11.95
 4492605739542347  14.95
 4492605768635795  25.95
```

Comment: Is your sample data from the erroneous rows or is it just generic data from your spreadsheet?

Comment: It's from the erroneous rows.  I have copied data from my good rows into the erroneous rows and the error persists.

Comment: Do all the values in your spreadsheet start with `44` or is it when they begin to start with `44` that you run into an error? Just trying to narrow it down :-)

Comment: All the values start with 44 you've gave me an idea.  I copied the data from the first row all the way down to the end of the data range and still got the error in line 144.

Comment: To follow up on @Mis's answer, do all of your values exceed the precision of 15 digits?

Comment: Forget that question, missed your comment.

Comment: They are all long digits however I did try to make them all 449260 and I still get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124314/discussion-between-jay-gould-and-missy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the Range object size. I tried replace the foreach to this and it worked (for me the null was occurring in line 102)

```
int maxRows = usedRange.Rows.Count;
for (int i=1;i<=maxRows;i++)
{
    // Column 1 is customer number
   // THE FOLLOWING LINE RETURNS NULL STARTING AT ROW 144
   cellValue = xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2 == null ? "" : xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();

    if (!(cellValue.Length >= 5 && cellValue.Length <= 20))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cellValue + " Must be between 5 and 20 Characters - File Will Not Be Processed Row#" + i.ToString());
        runProcess = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try it and let you know what the outcome is.